# Rendering const Variable in JSX after Form Submit

Tags: reactjs, next.js, formik, yup

To further learn and practice with Next.js, I am attempting to make a website that shortens a long URL like Tinyurl. However, I am having trouble rendering the shortened URL. I am using a form and on submitting that form the shortened URL is supposed to appear. Formik and Yup handle the form data and [studiohyperdrive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@studiohyperdrive/shortener)'s url-shortener shortens the URL. There is an object named `result` that returns an output like this:

```
{
  id: "6VYN9",
  original: "https://www.google.com",
  target: "https://short.er/6VYN9"
}
```

But I don't know how to pass or render the `target` in the Home component. When I type `<a>{result.target}</a>` Next.js says that `result` does not exist.

My code is as follows:

```
export default function Home() {
    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            link: "",
        },
        validationSchema: Yup.object({
            link: Yup.string()
                .matches(
                    /((https?):\/\/)?(www.)?[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z]{2,}){1,3}(#?\/?[a-zA-Z0-9#]+)*\/?(\?[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+=[a-zA-Z0-9-%]+&?)?$/,
                    "Please enter a vaild url"
                )
                .required("A URL is required"),
        }),
        onSubmit: (values) => {
            const shortener = new Shortener({
                target: "https://short.ie/",
                alphabet: "alphanumeric",
            });
            // what I'm trying to display:
            const result = shortener.shorten(values.link);
        },
    });
    
    return (
        <div id="container">
            <div className="header-container">
                <h1 id="header">URL Shortie</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="form-container">
                <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                    <label className="label">
                        {formik.touched.link && formik.errors.link ? formik.errors.link : "Your Long URL"}
                    </label>
                    <input
                        className="input"
                        type="url"
                        name="link"
                        value={formik.values.link}
                        onChange={formik.handleChange}
                        onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                        placeholder="Enter your link here"
                        required
                    />

                    <p className="label">Shortened URL</p>
                    <div className="input copy">
                        // how I'm trying to display it:
                        {/* <a href={result.original} target="_blank">{result.target}</a> */}
                        <a href="" target="_blank">{}</a>
                    </div>

                    <div className="button-container">
                        <input className="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Shorten Url" />

                        <button className="copy-btn">
                            <span class="material-symbols-outlined">content_copy</span>
                            Copy
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <h1 id="subheader">Previous URLs</h1>
                <div className="previous-urls-container"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the result as a state variable. For example

```js
const [shortUrl, setShortUrl] = useState(null);
```

then in your *submit* handler, set it

```js
setShortUrl(shortener.shorten(values.link));
```

and conditionally render it

```jsx
{shortUrl && (
  <a href={shortUrl.original} target="_blank">{shortUrl.target}</a>
)}
```

For more information, see [Managing State](https://react.dev/learn/managing-state)

---

Since the `Shortener` instance is reusable, I would define it outside your component. This will avoid recreating it on every submit of every render of your component.

For example

```js
const shortener = new Shortener({
  target: "https://short.ie/",
  alphabet: "alphanumeric",
});

export default function Home() {
  // ...
}
```